# MapBox IOS SDK Swift : how to show the user annotations from specific zoomLevel without delete and add again?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, mapbox

as you can see here, every time the zoom level changes, i am removing and adding the annotations, but the problem is that it is too slow and the app is stuck. i have search all over MapBox documentation but didn't found a better way to make it happen.

isFull , isMedium and isEmpty are just the flags for the zoom levels i need.

thank for the helpers :)

internal func mapView(mapView: MGLMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool)
    {
        if (mapView.zoomLevel > 14 )
        {

```
        isFull = true
        isMedium = false
        isEmpty = false
        if (gotMyHistory)
        {
            if (mapView.annotations?.count > 0){mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations!)}
        LoadAnnotation()
        }
    }else if (mapView.zoomLevel <= 14 && mapView.zoomLevel >= 8 && !isMedium )
    {

        isFull = false
        isMedium = true
        isEmpty = false
        if (gotMyHistory )
        {
            if (mapView.annotations?.count > 0){mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations!)}
            LoadAnnotation()
        }
    }else if (mapView.zoomLevel < 8 && !isEmpty)
    {
        isFull = false
        isMedium = false
        isEmpty = true
        if (gotMyHistory)
        {
            if (mapView.annotations?.count > 0){mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations!)}
        }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I realise that this is probably not relevant to the original poster since so much time has passed, but hopefully helps others.
I encountered the same problem and after 3 different implementations (first being with annotations like you), I found creating my own map layer to be the smoothest option.

```
  // Wait until the style is loaded before modifying the map style
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, didFinishLoading style: MGLStyle) {

    //Bicycle Parking Annotations Layer
    let bicycleParkingSource = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "bicycleParking", features: [], options: nil)
    self.bicycleParkingSource = bicycleParkingSource

    style.setImage(UIImage(named: "bicycleParking")!, forName: "bicycleParking") // referenced by an MGLSymbolStyleLayer’s iconImage

    let bicycleParkingSymbols = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: "bicycleParking", source: bicycleParkingSource)
    bicycleParkingSymbols.iconImageName = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: "bicycleParking")
    bicycleParkingSymbols.minimumZoomLevel = 12.0

    style.addSource(bicycleParkingSource)
    style.addLayer(bicycleParkingSymbols)
}
```

I actually found Mapbox to have a good tutorial for it after I finished and it helped improve my code. https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/examples/runtime-multiple-annotations/
As you can see you can set a maximum visible zoom level for layers. Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also give the source an option to do the same thing.
`MGLShapeSource(identifier: "bicycleParking", features: yourFeatures, options: [.minimumZoomLevel: 12.0])`

This would makes sure that all the layers on your source are hidden for any zoomLevel < 12 and you don't need to add the `minimumZoomLevel` for every layer on the source.

Answer (score 0):

What does your LoadAnnotation Function looks like ? The performance lack might be there, you could use dispatch_async, this was a performance boost for me

```
let priority = Int(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY.rawValue)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                //load your markers here
            }
        }
```